# Keep body background image expanded and centered across different resolutions

Tags: html, css

I made a website and I have a problem about vertical centering. My monitor is all right, but at a higher resolution tables remain on the top line and the image is reduced and the output from the table. How to keep things together?

http://marko8883.net84.net/

```
.body {
background-position: center center;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-color: #000000;  }

#tabela {
background-attachment: fixed;
background-image:url(images/zid3.gif);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position:center center;
width: 950px;
height: 800px;
cellpadding:5;
cellspacing:0;
margin:0 auto;  }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML in your post to make a concise self-contained example.

Comment: Btw, the effect is easily reproduced by browser's zoom feature (ctrl+scrollwheel).

Comment: @ Sparky: which part of html code you need?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set `position:absolute;` for all your elements, or use JavaScript to make page smaller/larger with resolutions, or windows size change.

Comment: I tried to do so and there was no better. If you could provide a link to JavaScript? thanks for trying